# are there good caching patterns on iOs?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm about to implement caching on my app, I imagine there are already good patterns on how to do that.
I think I'm going to use Core Data but I was wondering the best way to do that.
Most of the doc I found are just for Core Data tutorial.
What I do is to generate the NSManagedObject but then I also use a similar class with my additional methods, this to be decoupled from future fields addition keeping the generated one independent.
Is there some tutorial on the best way to handle object caching with Core Data?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For keeping the hand-written code separate from the machine-generated code when using Core Data, have a look at [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/). Very useful.

As far as caching goes, Core Data's pretty decent, and with judicious use of batch faulting and pre-fetching, you can fairly easily manage the number of trips to the persistent store. The faulting mechanism works well in my experience, so be wary of premature optimisation when it comes to Core Data.

The [advice Apple gives here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html) is good, in particular use the profiling tools to see the part of your app that isn't working efficiently, and then address that specifically, rather than spending time writing code for a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm checking mogenerator, I', wondering why Apple didn't include something like that, is maybe something they discourage?

Comment: They've certainly made it harder to integrate with Xcode, but I think that's more a side effect of the new architecture than a deliberate attempt to discourage/limit it.

Answer (score 1):

Caching to file system is discouraged on iOS. Use Core Data for permanent storage, not temporary caching when possible.

There are however two in memory caching facilities provided by Apple.

- `NSURLCache` for caching responses using the URL loading system (`NSURLConnection` and friends.). Simply create a new instance, and set it using `+[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:]`.
- `NSCache` for caching any object. Just create an instance, add and fetch cached object using keys like form a normal dictionary collection. Supports both count and cost limits, as well as locking cached objects using the `NSDiscardableContent` protocol.

You could also use a in-memory `NSPersistentStore` for Core Data if you like to work with managed objects, that are only to live for one execution of the app.

Comment: I think I'll use NSCache for in-memory caching but I need persistency for images. I read that saving on "disk" is preferred especially for large files.
I'm still wondering if there are no best practices for this kind of handling that most of the applications have to do.

Comment: Implementing the `NSCacheDelegate` protocol to delete files on "disk", in conjunction of using `NSDiscardableContent` to purge images from memory has worked very well for me. Basically I add `restoreContent` and `removeContent` as friends to `discardContentIfPossible`.